# Incomplete Initialisation in Julia

Tags: struct, initialization, julia

I want to initialise part of a Datatype in Julia, I currently have:

```
mutable struct Foo
    bar::Int
    baz::Int
    maz::Int
    Foo(maz=2)=new(maz)
end

foo=Foo()
println(foo)
```

However this creates an object which is `Foo(2, 0, 0)`

How do I do so that I get `Foo(0, 0, 2)`

Note: I would prefer to not have to do a complete initialisation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `new()` (see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#Incomplete-Initialization-1) for details):

```
julia> mutable struct Foo
           bar::Int
           baz::Int
           maz::Int
           function Foo(maz=2)
               foo = new()
               foo.maz = maz
               return foo
           end
       end

julia> foo=Foo()
Foo(139985835568976, 8, 2)
```

Note that `bar` and `baz` fields are not set to `0` but uninitialized.

Comment: The Julia guide was confusing because it did incomplete initialisation along with a recursive object but your example made it clear.